# Jquery drag and drop div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have HTML like:

```
  <div class="form-container-ingredients">
     <div id="removable-ingredient-container-1"> 
       ... other elements
     </div>
     <div id="removable-ingredient-container-2"> 
       ... other elements
     </div>
     <div id="removable-ingredient-container-3"> 
       ... other elements
     </div>
  </div>
```

So this represents a number of rows, and each row contains the same elements. I also have buttons to add new rows and remove rows. This works.

Now I would like to add the possibility to move rows, for example, move removable-ingredient-container-1 after removable-ingredient-container-3.

Does anyone has an example or tutorial on how to do that in jQuery, based on my example?

Thank you,
L

Comment: jQUeryUI sortable()? http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) has a [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) plugin that you can use to achieve that effect cleanly and easily.